# Where is my flex code syntactically incorrect?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I am trying to recreate my grid layout using flex. The flex code I have commented out is wrong I think due to me setting the width incorrectly in my .container class. The grid auto property assigns the columns automatically within my .even-columns class according to my current width assigned in .container but I'm not sure how to re-write this using flex.

Am I missing the correct width property or should I have assigned flex to my container instead?

```css
/* CONTAINER CLASS */

.container {
  --max-width: 1110px;
  --padding: 1rem;
  width: min(var(--max-width), 100% - (var(--padding) * 2));
  margin-inline: auto;
}


/* EVEN COLUMNS CLASS */

.even-columns {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
  /* Trying same layout with flexbox
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;*/
}

@media (min-width: 50em) {
  .even-columns {
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
    /*Trying same layout with flexbox
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;*/
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Main -->
<main>
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="even-columns">
        <div>
          <h1 class="fs-primary-heading fw-bold">Bring everyone together to build better products.</h1>
          <p>Manage makes it simple for software developers to chorolate their projects and share them with other teams and colleagues. </p>
          <button class="button">Get Started</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="images/illustration-intro.svg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>


  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="even-columns">
        <div>
          <h2 class="fs-secondary-heading fw-bold">Manage your team</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
          <ul class="numbered-items" role="list">
            <li>
              <h3 class="fs-600 fw-bold">Advertising</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis laborum at quia odio laudantium qui incidunt, laboriosam facere dolores deleniti quos quod reiciendis deserunt officiis explicabo impedit ducimus, expedita consequatur?</p>
            </li>

            <li>
              <h3 class="fs-600 fw-bold">Version Control</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis laborum at quia odio laudantium qui incidunt, laboriosam facere dolores deleniti quos quod reiciendis deserunt officiis explicabo impedit ducimus, expedita consequatur?</p>
            </li>

            <li>
              <h3 class="fs-600 fw-bold">Database Management</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis laborum at quia odio laudantium qui incidunt, laboriosam facere dolores deleniti quos quod reiciendis deserunt officiis explicabo impedit ducimus, expedita consequatur?</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Your [flex](https://jsfiddle.net/vfc86L7w/show) version looks better than the grid one

Comment: @mplungjan The grid version results in a two column layout but the flex doesn't, I'm not sure why?

Comment: Ah. Ok. The grid version looked weird on a big screen

Comment: Am I right in thinking I need to apply flex to the container as well? I normally set display: flex on the container and the width of the container to max-width: 100%. For a two column layout I set max-width: 50% for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with your grid rules and flexbox rules display content in opposite ways.

Grid is working properly with `min-width` because you are telling it to fraction container when its width is 50em and more. So content is divided in two columns of the same row.

But the same mediquery with your flexbox code tells it to display content in column when width is more then 50em, which is complitely opposite.

In other words if we look at it from `mobile-first` perspective. Your grid rules will display content in column, but your flex rules will display content in row.

You have two solutions:

First: you can leave the code as it is and modify `min-width` to `max-width` and flexbox will work just fine.

Second: if you want `mobile first` design then you dont have to modify mediquery's application rule.

Just add `flex-direction: row;` to `.even-columns` that is inside mediaquery and add  `flex-direction: column;` to `.even-columns` that is outside mediaquery

Additionally, if you want the columns to have the same width you will have to define `width` for the children of `.even-columns`

This is where grid goes better because using it you dont have do define all these styles that goes to container's children.

```css
/* CONTAINER CLASS */

.container {
  --max-width: 1110px;
  --padding: 1rem;
  width: min(var(--max-width), 100% - (var(--padding) * 2));
  margin-inline: auto;
}


/* EVEN COLUMNS CLASS */

.even-columns {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
}

@media (max-width: 50em) {
  .even-columns {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

}

.even-columns > div {
  min-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Main -->
<main>
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="even-columns">
        <div>
          <h1 class="fs-primary-heading fw-bold">Bring everyone together to build better products.</h1>
          <p>Manage makes it simple for software developers to chorolate their projects and share them with other teams and colleagues. </p>
          <button class="button">Get Started</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="images/illustration-intro.svg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>


  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="even-columns">
        <div>
          <h2 class="fs-secondary-heading fw-bold">Manage your team</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
          <ul class="numbered-items" role="list">
            <li>
              <h3 class="fs-600 fw-bold">Advertising</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis laborum at quia odio laudantium qui incidunt, laboriosam facere dolores deleniti quos quod reiciendis deserunt officiis explicabo impedit ducimus, expedita consequatur?</p>
            </li>

            <li>
              <h3 class="fs-600 fw-bold">Version Control</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis laborum at quia odio laudantium qui incidunt, laboriosam facere dolores deleniti quos quod reiciendis deserunt officiis explicabo impedit ducimus, expedita consequatur?</p>
            </li>

            <li>
              <h3 class="fs-600 fw-bold">Database Management</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis laborum at quia odio laudantium qui incidunt, laboriosam facere dolores deleniti quos quod reiciendis deserunt officiis explicabo impedit ducimus, expedita consequatur?</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is this the correct way to select the child elements - .even-columns > div {
  max-width: 50%;
}

Comment: Well `max-width` would take 50% if content is long enough. In case of `<h2 class="fs-secondary-heading fw-bold">Manage your team</h2>`, it will not take 50% width of container, but only the necessary to fit content.  It should be `width` or `min-width` if you want columns to be even

Comment: I will add snippet

Comment: ah i see, i just set the .even-columns > div { min-width: 50% } outside of the media query and that seems to have turned it into equal 50% columns for the divs. Does that sound right? I don't know if selecting ever div child is correct however

Comment: that snippet works great, only problem is the unordered list part of my footer has breached it's 50% container for some reason, every other section works fine though

Comment: If you can't solve that problem open another issue for me so i can have a proper look